# MySQL compare databases and add missing columns

Tags: mysql

I have two quite large databases which are almost the same in every way however one has a lot of extra columns in each table which the second one does not.

Leaving rows as just default how would I go about comparing the tables and adding the missing columns defined in the first database to the second?

Example:
Database 1 (id, name, surname, extra)
Database 2 (id, name, surname)

I want to add 'extra' column defined in Database 1 to Database 2.

I don't care too much about the actual extra data, it can be set as the default defined in Database 1. The columns are all that is needed.

Just to note: I have tried tools such as Toad however they all want to change the data in the second database to match the first which I do not want.

Database 1 example table (CollectionSearchIndexAttributes):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CollectionSearchIndexAttributes` (
  `cID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ak_meta_title` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `ak_meta_description` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `ak_meta_keywords` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `ak_icon_dashboard` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `ak_exclude_nav` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `ak_exclude_page_list` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `ak_header_extra_content` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `ak_tags` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ak_is_featured` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `ak_exclude_search_index` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `ak_exclude_sitemapxml` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `ak_job_posting_department` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ak_job_location` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `ak_exclude_subpages_from_nav` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `ak_thumbnail` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `ak_blog_entry_topics` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `ak_project_topics` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `ak_project_client` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `ak_project_tasks` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ak_project_skills` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Database 2 example table (CollectionSearchIndexAttributes):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CollectionSearchIndexAttributes` (
  `cID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ak_meta_title` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `ak_meta_description` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `ak_meta_keywords` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `ak_icon_dashboard` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `ak_exclude_nav` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `ak_exclude_page_list` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `ak_header_extra_content` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `ak_tags` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ak_is_featured` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `ak_exclude_search_index` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `ak_exclude_sitemapxml` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

As you can see database 1's table has 8 columns that database 2's table does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the procedure you can use,just update it as per the db names.
also, i am assuming here that all the tables exists in both the dbs.

here are the two sample tables

```
mysql> select table_name, column_name
    -> from information_schema.columns 
    -> where table_schema = 'db1'
    -> order by table_name
    -> ;
+------------+-------------+
| table_name | column_name |
+------------+-------------+
| t1         | c1          |
| t1         | c2          |
| t2         | c1          |
| t2         | c2          |
| t2         | c3          |
| t3         | c1          |
| t3         | c2          |
| t3         | c3          |
+------------+-------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> select table_name, column_name
    -> from information_schema.columns 
    -> where table_schema = 'db2'
    -> order by table_name
    -> ;
+------------+-------------+
| table_name | column_name |
+------------+-------------+
| t1         | c1          |
| t2         | c1          |
| t2         | c2          |
+------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and here is the procedure

```
drop procedure sync_tables;

delimiter //
create procedure sync_tables()
begin

declare tab_name  VARCHAR(100);
declare col_name  VARCHAR(100);
declare col_type  VARCHAR(100);

declare sql_cmd  VARCHAR(100);

declare done int default FALSE;

declare cur cursor for 
select concat('alter table ' , 'db2','.',table_name, ' add column ', column_name , ' ' , column_type ) as sql_cmd_c
  from information_schema.columns
  where table_schema = 'db1' 
     and
          concat( table_name, '_', column_name) not in (
              select concat( table_name,'_',column_name) as db2p
              from information_schema.columns   
              where table_schema = 'db2'
);
declare continue handler for not found  set done = TRUE;
read_loop : LOOP
   open cur;
   fetch cur into sql_cmd;
     set @sqlcmd := sql_cmd;
     prepare sqlcmd from @sqlcmd;
     execute sqlcmd;
     if done then 
        leave read_loop;
     end if;
     select 'bhavin';
end LOOP;

end//
delimiter ;
```

and here is the updated tables after running call

```
mysql> select table_name, column_name
    -> from information_schema.columns 
    -> where table_schema = 'db1'
    -> order by table_name
    -> ;
+------------+-------------+
| table_name | column_name |
+------------+-------------+
| t1         | c1          |
| t1         | c2          |
| t2         | c1          |
| t2         | c2          |
| t2         | c3          |
| t3         | c1          |
| t3         | c2          |
| t3         | c3          |
+------------+-------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> select table_name, column_name
    -> from information_schema.columns 
    -> where table_schema = 'db2'
    -> order by table_name
    -> ;
+------------+-------------+
| table_name | column_name |
+------------+-------------+
| t1         | c1          |
| t1         | c2          |
| t2         | c1          |
| t2         | c2          |
| t2         | c3          |
+------------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of a tool to do this, but it is pretty easy to do with some scripting.

In MYSQL, databases have an implicit `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` with tables in it that have information about the other tables in that datbase.

You can join the tables using

```
SELECT c1.table_name, c1.column_name
FROM db_1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c1 LEFT JOIN
    db_2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c2
      ON  c1.table_name = c2.table_name AND c1.column_name = c2.column_name
WHERE c2.column_name IS NULL
```

This is assuming db_1 is the first and db_2 is the second.

This will help find the columns, and then you can easily add in the missing ones.

Comment: Would this also copy data from db 1 to 2? If so that would cause a lot of problems. Also, how would I get this to iterate over every table in db2? I do have PHP at my disposal if needed.

Comment: I added an example table to my question if you could please elaborate on your answer that would be a great help.

Comment: this does not work.